# airflow on kubernetes: How to install extra python packages?

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, bitnami

i installed airflow using bitnami repo:  To install extra python packages i mounted an extra volume[image]

I prepared my requirements.txt file and then i created a ConfigMap using *kubectl create -n airflow configmap requirements --from-file=requirements.txt* after this i upgraded airflow using helm upgrade....

But in my dags file, i'm still getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'"

Comment: what is the executor you are using ? If the answer is k8s then you need to add those extra packages in your airflow image. Please let me know if that helps ?

Comment: yess k8s, how can i add them pls?

Comment: UPDATE !!!!!
I solved the problem by adding extraVolumeMounts and extraVolumes to the airflow web pod and  scheduler pod

Comment: Hi Elpis, Could you post a solution? It would be more visible to the community.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-data-pipelines-using-apache-airflow-on-kubernetes-4506baea3ce0 . in the step where i should add extraVolumeMounts  and extraVolumes to the worker pod, i also added to same values to the web pod  and the scheduler pod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting this as Community wiki for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

As @Elpis wrote in the comments section, he followed [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-data-pipelines-using-apache-airflow-on-kubernetes-4506baea3ce0) to install Apache Airflow on Kubernetes.

And he solved the problem by adding `extraVolumeMounts` and `extraVolumes` to the **worker pod**, and also to the **web pod** and to the **scheduler pod**.

```
extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: requirements
    mountPath: /bitnami/python/

## Add extra volumes
extraVolumes:
  - name: requirements
    configMap:
# Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
# to add to the container
      name: requirements
```

After that, all extra Python packages were installed.

Comment: the worker is fine, but on airflow GUI, errors, no module found